# Selecting peculiar XML tags with phpQuery

Tags: php, xml, phpquery

[phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) is a really nice tool which has helped me tremendously in the past parse well-formed XHTML and XML documents, but I have recently run into a problem trying to select elements that have colons in their tagname, such as the following:

```
<isc:thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/foo_thumb.jpg]]></isc:thumb>
```

I've tried to use the `pq()` function to select all of these elements:

```
foreach ( pq("isc:thumb") as $thumbnail ) {
  print pq( $thumbnail )->text();
}
```

Unfortunately this is doing nothing. If I try another element, like a tagname of `id`, the results pop up as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to find a `thumb` element which belongs to the `isc` namespace (see [XML namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace)); not a tag named `isc:thumb`.

phpQuery can happily query for namespaced elements, just not like you are trying to do. Instead, simply provide the tag in the form `namespace|tagname` (i.e. `isc|thumb`). It is also worth noting that the namespace will have to be registered with phpQuery's XPath handler (which is just a [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/domxpath) object) for it to be able to recognise the namespace.

Here's a quick example with a sample XML document (obviously, use your own XML and be sure to provide the correct namespace URI).

```
phpQuery::newDocumentXML('<root xmlns:isc="urn.example.isc">
  <isc:thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/foo_thumb.jpg]]></isc:thumb>
  <isc:thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/bar_thumb.jpg]]></isc:thumb>
</root>
');
phpQuery::getDocument()->xpath->registerNamespace('isc', 'urn.example.isc');
foreach ( pq("isc|thumb") as $thumbnail ) {
    echo pq( $thumbnail )->text() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
http://example.com/foo_thumb.jpg
http://example.com/bar_thumb.jpg
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you for the attention to detail.

Comment: What if XML looks like this `<root xmlns:isc="urn.example.isc">
  <isc:thumb> <isc:more>test</isc:more></isc:thumb>
</root>`

Comment: `pq("isc|more", $thumbnail )` does not show antyhing